# React - How to align text and img in same line

Tags: css, reactjs

I'd like to align some text with a logo on the same line:

```
                    <div id="container" style="white-space:nowrap">
                        <div id="image" style="display:inline;">
                            <Link href="" target="_blank">
                                <img
                                    src={img}
                                    loading="lazy"
                                    width="40px"
                                    height="40px"
                                    alt=""
                                />
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div id="texts" style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;">
                            <strong> 75 </strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But when I try to run it, I receive these errors:

```
  Line 61:41:  Style prop value must be an object                                                                         react/style-prop-object
  Line 62:41:  Style prop value must be an object                                                                         react/style-prop-object
  Line 73:41:  Style prop value must be an object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you need to use in style in object,

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

```
style={{
      whiteSpace:'nowrap',
      display:'inline',
      
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before we can answer the question you ask in the title of this post, you have to fix your inline styles, hence the error you receive from React. *The answer to your question using CSS will be at the bottom of the post.*

When using inline styles in React, you will need to create an object. An object is the use of key, value pairs. So, using the code given in your example, `style="display:inline;"` is not an object, and thus will not work as you have seen. To make this inline style work, you will need to do one of the following.

1. **Create an object within the JSX**

This method can get messy, so if you are planning to write all your styles as inline styles, I suggest using method 2.

To do this, you can follow @RiTeSh 's example. You will need to create an object and pass that to the element's `style` prop, **WHICH CANNOT BE A STRING**, as you can see from the errors you are getting. You can do the following:

```
// Notice how the value is the only string in the object.
style={{
      whiteSpace:'nowrap',
      display:'inline',
      
    }}
```

And to see what this would look like when used in an element:

```
<div style={{whiteSpace:'nowrap',  display:'inline'}} >
 Hello World
</div>
```

2. **Store the styles in a variable**

Compared to method 1, this is a much cleaner way to add inline styles as it doesn't create a jumbled mess in your `render()` function.

Before you reach the `render()` function, create an object and store it in a variable like the one below.

```
const styleObject = {
      whiteSpace:'nowrap',
      display:'inline',
      
    };

return (
 // Your JSX here
);
```

And when you apply the `styleObject` to the JSX element, it should look like the following:

```
return(
 <div style={styleObject} >
  Hello World
 </div>
);
```

**Make img and text appear on the same line**

This is quite a simple answer if you use the `display: flex` property on the wrapper element, which, in your case, is the `div` with an id of `container`. [Here is a simple read about flexbox from W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

With inline styles on the container element:

```
style={{display: 'flex'}}
```

With CSS:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`style` **prop** takes an object.

Full code:

```
<div id="container" style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
      <div id="image" style={{ display: "inline" }}>
        <Link href="" target="_blank">
          <img src={img} loading="lazy" style={{ width: "40px", height: "40px" }} alt="" />
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div id="texts" style={{ display: "inline", whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
        <strong> 75 </strong>
      </div>
</div>
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wind-poegp?file=/src/App.js)